# How to get Graphs and Table inside same frame one at time in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, tkinter

I searched a lot but till i am not getting Graphs and Tables working in `PySimpleGUI` inside same frame.

What i achieved so far :

i have one `dropdown menu` where symbol of shares come.
next to it is `graph button` and one `table button`.
here different graph is comming.

What i want:
what i want is a `sigle frame` below `buttons` where graph will come and
inside same frame when i press `table button` table should be shown.

So i want single frame destroying every time and generating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of time, it's very difficult to understand what you mean by some simple sentences.

Maybe following example code OK for you,

[image]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

headings = ['President', 'Date of Birth']
data = [
    ['Ronald Reagan', 'February 6'],
    ['Abraham Lincoln', 'February 12'],
    ['George Washington', 'February 22'],
    ['Andrew Jackson', 'March 15'],
    ['Thomas Jefferson', 'April 13'],
]
width, height = 353, 100

sg.theme('DarkBlue')
sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 12))

column_layout = [
    [sg.Table(data, headings=headings, pad=(0, 0), auto_size_columns=False,
        col_widths=(20, 15), num_rows=5, hide_vertical_scroll=True,
        justification='left', key='TABLE')],]

frame_layout = [
    [sg.Graph((width, height), (0, 0), (width, height), pad=(0, 0),
        background_color='green', key='GRAPH')],
    [sg.Column(column_layout, pad=(0, 0), visible=True, key='COLUMN',
        metadata=True)],]

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Frame Visible'), sg.Button('Table Visible')],
    [sg.Column(frame_layout, pad=(0, 0), key='FRAME', visible=True,
        metadata=True)],]

window  = sg.Window("Title", layout, size=(375, 265), finalize=True)
frame   = window['FRAME']
column  = window['COLUMN']

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == 'Frame Visible':
        visible = not frame.metadata
        frame.update(visible=visible)
        frame.metadata = visible

    elif event == 'Table Visible':
        if frame.metadata:
            visible = not column.metadata
            column.update(visible=visible)
            column.metadata = visible

window.close()
```

Comment: Element.visible is now a readonly property.  It was released in 4.33.0. Maybe could use here?

Comment: It may means samething as I put visible in `metadata`, and it will still work if someone use old version PySimpleGUI.

Comment: can you post with graph as i m not able to that

Comment: Most of time, it's very difficult to understand what you mean by some simple sentences.

Comment: Right... `metadata` is the more portable/backward-compatible way. `visible` is a recent addition and only in the tkinter port. Very nicely done! As usual, "right answer"